# How to get Spring Security ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider working?

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, ldap

In a Spring Boot application I want to perform an authentication against an Active Directory. As an information in advance, the following cli ldapsearch is working and delivers information as expectected:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=boss,ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pw1234 -h ldap.example.com -p 389 -b "ou=students,dc=example,dc=com" "samaccountname=student42@example.com"
```

So in the yaml-configuration I have set up the ldap context source as follows:

```yaml
spring.ldap.base: "dc=example,dc=com"
spring.ldap.urls: "ldap://ldap.example.com:389"
spring.ldap.username: "cn=boss"
spring.ldap.password: "pw1234"
```

This set up worked for a local OpenDJ installation using Spring's `BindAuthenticator`, but now I'm trying to authenticate against a real world `Active Directory`. For that I've set up an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("", "ldap://ldap.example.com:389");

    // provider.setSearchFilter("(uid={0})"); // do I need this?

    return provider;
}
```

Unfortunetely, all I get is the following error:

```
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider:  Authentication for student42@example.com failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 ]
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider:  Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
```

I don't get any further information, like whether the initial binding with the manager-dn (cn=boss) was successful, but I assume, that there is something more to configure, which I just don't know. Maybe I have to set `manager-dn` and `manager-password` somewhere explicitly, but if so, where?

Does anybody know where to start fixing that problem?

#### Edit:

As requested, here the most important results of the ldapsearch:

```
dn:: Q049MmFiZWUgc3R1ZGVudCA0MiAzNDQyMDEwMTk2LE9VPXN0dWRlbnRzLERDPWV4YW1wbGUsREM9Y29t
cn: 2abee student 42 3442010196
description: 3442010196
displayName: 42 student (2abee)
distinguishedName:: Q049MmFiZWUgc3R1ZGVudCA0MiAzNDQyMDEwMTk2LE9VPXN0dWRlbnRzLERDPWV4YW1wbGUsREM9Y29t
generationQualifier: 3442010196
givenName: 42
mail: student42@example.com
memberOf:: Q049MmFiZWUsT1U9c3R1ZGVudHMsREM9ZXhhbXBsZSxEQz1jb20=
name: 2abee student 42 3442010196
sn: student
sAMAccountName: student42@example.com
userPrincipalName: student42@example.com
```

The credential entered into the login form are:

`username: student42@example.com`
`password: secret`

Comment: Please show us the results of you `ldapsearch` for the important attributes. Just append their names at the end of the command: `dn cn sn sAMAccountName mail`. Also confirm what the user puts in their login form. Based on your search, it is `student42@example.com` (and not just `student42`).

Comment: Thanks @ixe013, I've updated the post as required.

Answer (score 0):

The `cn` attribute exists in Active Directory, but you need to put the distinguished name (`dn`) in your configuration, the same you used in your `ldapsearch` command line.

```
spring.ldap.base: "dc=example,dc=com"
spring.ldap.urls: "ldap://ldap.example.com:389"
spring.ldap.username: "cn=boss,ou=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
spring.ldap.password: "pw1234"
```

Now the default search in the class [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider is `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L131). That means the user needs to enter the value of their `userPrincipalName` attribute. Changing it to `(uid={0})` (with `setSeachFilter`) will not work, keep the default.

The [exception you get is thrown at line 229](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L229). Reading the code, it looks like this is happening:

1. [`doAuthentication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L162C43-L162C43) receives the username and password
2. [`bindAsUser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L204) does not search, but attempts to login with the supplied username and password.
3. It can't login so an exception is thrown. Are you sure you have the right password?

In other words, the code behaves like this:

```
ldapsearch -D "student42@example.com" -w secret -h ldap.example.com -p 389 -b "ou=students,dc=example,dc=com" "userPrincipalName=student42@example.com"
```

The `spring.ldap.username` and `spring.ldap.password` are not used in the code. You can remove them and you will get the same error.

[Simple bind over a non-encrypted connection is often blocked](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/2020-and-2023-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a), but it looks like it work for you. Still you should use LDAPS...

Comment: Thank you for your help @ixe013. Although your suggestion seems logical, it unfortunately doesn't change anything. Is there a way to figure out if at least the initial binding was sucessful? I cant't tell exactly, whether the first lookup to obtain the dn of the authenticating user worked properly or the later binding of the authenticating user failed. I don't have access to the AD server, so I have to somehow figure that out preferably within Spring Boot itself. Many thanks.